# How @Transactional works in my case ? Spring service

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have **serviceImpl** implemented by **service**.
Can I have:

- service public,
- serviceImpl package private

and add @Transactional to public method in serviceImpl ?
Should it works ?

Comment: yes it should and will (used that same structure on multiple projects).

Comment: Yes, will works.